# Reset Doctorine object to original values after Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, oop

I have a Symfony form where my customers can downgrade their account. Only when downgrading a account there is an delay (one full month) before the changes are effective. With an upgrade the changes are right a way effective.

After the validation of the account form i check if it is an downgrade op upgrade. With an upgrade i just flush the changed in the account so they are stored.

```
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->flush();
```

But when it is an downgrade i want to reset the object to its original values, so before the form changes. Then I add an value in the downgrade field of the later change.

I tried to unset the $account and then load it again. But I get the field values that are changed in the form. Is there a way to reset it?

```
                unset($account);

            $account = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('MyBundle:Account')
                ->findOneBy(
                    array('id' => $this->get('session')->get('AccountId'))
                );
```

Comment: are you sure thats not the browser history?

Comment: There is no refresh between it so could be. After a page refresh the old values are back. Only I need to find a way to reset it without a refresh.

Comment: $entityManager->refresh($account);

Comment: Thanks Cerad, your solution works